# 401 Unauthorized on Dataverse Web API post method

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dataverse

I am using Dataverse via the Web API to access data from a server. This works very well in itself. All unlocked tables/entities can be accessed via the corresponding URL using GET method and also return valid results. That means the access and the authentication via security token works.

However, when I call the POST-Method to exactly the same table/entity, I get an error message back:

> __checkpoint ⇢ 401 UNAUTHORIZED from POST https://ANONYM.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/

The role assigned to the application user actually has explicit write permissions to the table.

The post looks like this:

```
POST /api/data/v9.2/ANONYMtime-acquisitions HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/1.1.2
host: ANONYM.crm4.dynamics.com
ACCEPT: */*
content-type: application/json
content-length: 282

{"cr2a0_id":0,"cr2a0_Abweichung":7.5,"cr2a0_Datum":"Sat Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 2020","cr2a0_Ist-
Arbeitszeit":7.5,"cr2a0_Mitarbeiter":"ANONYM","cr2a0_Pause":0. 0,"cr2a0_Soll-
Arbeitszeit":0.0,"cr2a0_Wochentag":"ANONYM","cr2a0_Beginn":"09:00","cr2a0_Ende":"16:30",
"cr2a0_Info":""}
```

I would have expected that the writing access also works. What else could be the reason for this?

Comment: so by API the GET works but the POST doesn't and the method you are using has the security roles to perform the operation? can you write down the complete POST call with the body?

Comment: My understanding is that the security role should have the permissions. At least according to the editor at crm4.dynamics.com/biz/roles the security role is allowed to create, read, write and delete. I add the http post in the original thread post

Comment: that POST message has several errors, like the name of fields and the date format, try to generate the request using my tool Dataverse REST Builder https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB

Comment: Thank you for your respsonse and your help. I tried to send the request using your tool and Postman. Unfortunately the same behavior. Get works including the authentication and the token, a post does not. I would have also been surprised why then a 401 comes back. This has nothing to do with the formatting of the request.

Comment: Did you generate access token like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/nNAOjcj.png)?

Comment: Ha. that was the right hint. The token had to be created again in Postman, then both the Post and the Get worked. Thanks! Then I have to see that now the application sends the request in the same way :)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added API permission:

[image]

I generated the **auth-code** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=redirectUri
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/user_impersonation
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated the **access token** by using below parameters:

```http
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/user_impersonation
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:redirectURi
code:code
```

[image]

By using the above access token I am able to make the GET request successfully as below:

[image]

If still the issue occurs, make sure to assign Security role like below:

[image]

And check the **version of the CRM** like below:

[image]

To make a POST query, **refer** the below blog:

[Dynamics CRM 365 WEB API Common Errors and Resolution – xrm CRM Dynamics by Bipin Kumar](https://xrmdynamicscrm.wordpress.com/2020/06/08/dynamics-crm-365-web-api-common-errors-and-resolution/)